# Finding points on a slope with sorting Java

Tags: java

So I'm working on an assignment and I'm very stuck.
The assingment is this one http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/cos226/assignments/lines.html
Basically it involves writing 3 classes. The first one, point.java is used to keep information about a point in a XY-plane.
The assignment then asks that you find every combo of 4 points on the same line(that have the same slope)
First you do it with Brute.java, where you compare every possible combination, and then you do it with Fast.jave where you choose a starting point and compare from there and then don't use that point again. That way you avoid checking the same points.

The part that I'm stuck on is the last one, Fast.java.
I get almost the correct output except for the fact that the last two lines are swapped.
Given the input

```
15
10000 0
8000 2000
2000 8000
0  10000

20000 0
18000 2000
2000 18000

10000 20000
30000 0
0 30000
20000 10000

13000 0
11000 3000
5000 12000
9000 6000
```

I'm sorting the array before I find the points on the slope.
The sorted array, before the call to getLines then looks like this:

```
(10000, 0)
(8000, 2000)
(2000, 8000)
(0, 10000)
(20000, 0)
(18000, 2000)
(2000, 18000)
(10000, 20000)
(30000, 0)
(0, 30000)
(20000, 10000)
(13000, 0)
(11000, 3000)
(5000, 12000)
(9000, 6000)
```

Here is my Point class:

```
  public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {

public final int x, y;

// compare points by slope
public final Comparator<Point> SLOPE_ORDER = new Comparator<Point>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Point arg0, Point arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(slopeTo(arg0) < slopeTo(arg1)){
                    return -1;
                }
                if(slopeTo(arg0) > slopeTo(arg1)){
                    return 1;
                }
                else{
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        };

// create the point (x, y)
public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// plot this point to standard drawing
public void draw() {
    /* DO NOT MODIFY */
    StdDraw.point(x, y);
}

// draw line between this point and that point to standard drawing
public void drawTo(Point that) {
    /* DO NOT MODIFY */
    StdDraw.line(this.x, this.y, that.x, that.y);
}

// slope between this point and that point
public double slopeTo(Point that) {
    // TODO: Implement this

    if(this.x == that.x){
        return Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    }
    else if(that.y - this.y == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(this.x == that.x){
        return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }
    else{
        return (((double)that.y - (double)this.y)/((double)that.x - (double)this.x));
    }
}

/**
 * Is this point lexicographically smaller than that one? comparing
 * y-coordinates and breaking ties by x-coordinates
 */
public int compareTo(Point that) {
    // TODO: Implement this
    if(this.y < that.y){
        return -1;
    }
    else if(this.y > that.y){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        if(this.x < that.x){
            return -1;
        }
        else if(this.x > that.x){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my fast.java class:

```
private static void getLines(Point[] points) {
   Point p = points[0];
   Point[] lines = new Point[points.length];
   lines[0] = p;
   int pointsOnLine = 0;
   double lastSlope = p.slopeTo(points[1]);
   for(int i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
       Point newPoint = points[i];
       double slope = p.slopeTo(newPoint);
       if(slope == lastSlope) {
           pointsOnLine++;
           lines[pointsOnLine] = newPoint;
       }
       else {
           if(pointsOnLine >= 3) {
               printLine(lines, pointsOnLine + 1);
           }
           pointsOnLine = 1;
           lines[1] = newPoint;
       }
       lastSlope = slope;
   }

   if(pointsOnLine >= 3) {
       printLine(lines, pointsOnLine + 1);
   }
}

private static void printLine(Point[] lines, int size) {
   Arrays.sort(lines, 1, size);
   if(lines[0].compareTo(lines[1]) < 0) {
       StdOut.print(lines[0]);
       for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
           StdOut.print(" -> " + lines[i]);
       }
       StdOut.println();
   }
}
```

And my main function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   In in = new In();
   int N = in.readInt();
   Point[] points = new Point[N];
   for(int i=0; i< N; i++) {
       int x = in.readInt();
       int y = in.readInt();
       points[i] = new Point(x,y);
   }

   in.close();
   Point [] pointsCopy = Arrays.copyOf(points, points.length);
   for (Point originPoint : points) {
       Arrays.sort(pointsCopy, originPoint.SLOPE_ORDER);
       getLines(pointsCopy);
   }
}
```

My program outputs

```
(10000, 0) -> (8000, 2000) -> (2000, 8000) -> (0, 10000)
(10000, 0) -> (13000, 0) -> (20000, 0) -> (30000, 0)
(30000, 0) -> (20000, 10000) -> (10000, 20000) -> (0, 30000)
(13000, 0) -> (11000, 3000) -> (9000, 6000) -> (5000, 12000)
```

While the correct output is

```
(10000, 0) -> (8000, 2000) -> (2000, 8000) -> (0, 10000)
(10000, 0) -> (13000, 0) -> (20000, 0) -> (30000, 0)
(13000, 0) -> (11000, 3000) -> (9000, 6000) -> (5000, 12000)
(30000, 0) -> (20000, 10000) -> (10000, 20000) -> (0, 30000)
```

Anyone that can see where I'm going wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: It might be helpful if you had it print out the sorted array of points before running `getLines` and showed us what that looked like. Also posting the code of your `Point` object so we can see your custom comparator would be helpful. Last, try to summarize the assignment in your own words so that if someone comes along later when the link is broken, they can still understand the question.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the question based on your suggestions :)

Comment: Cool. One other thing, are you sure the code from your `Point` class is correct? Shouldn't it have a `compareTo` method?

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Copied the wrong code. Should be right now

Comment: Can you try changing the `compare` method to simply `return slopeto(arg0) - slopeto(arg1)`? Please let me know what happens.

Comment: I changed it to `return (int)(slopeTo(arg0) - slopeTo(arg1))` because the compare function has to return an int. 
The output then changes to
 `(10000, 0) -> (8000, 2000) -> (2000, 8000) -> (0, 10000)`

`(13000, 0) -> (11000, 3000) -> (9000, 6000) -> (5000, 12000)`

Comment: Ok. I can't compile your code now but I want to look into this more for you. Hopefully you get an answer soon but if not check back later today - I will compile this and debug it when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

The output will follow order present inside `pointsCopy` array. The `Arrays.sort` is sorting in a manner that results in your output. You can rearrange elements in the `pointsCopy` array or change array sorting logic to get desired output.

Comment: I'm actually not sure how I would do this. Since Point is an object, can I use something else than SLOPE_ORDER as a comparator in the Arrays.sort function?